# Django Prefetch object and only fails

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models Product an Categories. between them there is a many-to-many-relation.

I have the following code:

In view:

```
context['products']Product.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('categories', queryset=Category.objects.only('name')))
```

In template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.categories.all.0.name}}
```

In this case `prefetch_related` is ignore, and it exeutes anew query in categories for each product.

If I remove `only`, it executes just 2 queries

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a queryset with only the name field, as Django will at least need the product_id to match the Category object with the Product - since you have excluded it, Django will automatically make a separate query each time to fetch it. This happens at query time, even before the object it sent to the template.

`Category.objects.only('name', 'product_id')` would work.

Comment: error: Category has no field named 'product_id' ; probabilly because is many to many and not FK

Comment: In that case I'm not sure you can make this work - there might be a way, but I don't know what it is. Are you sure you really need `only`? It feels like an over optimisation.

Comment: I have 10 attributes on the Model, and I need just one